# How to fix "When I close app Sending packets also stopped"? Android

Tags: java, android, android-service, tcpclient

I create a tcp client to send and receive files and text. communication betweent tcp client and server is all Ok. I am sending packet in a thread. when user close app then thread also stopped in which process of message sending is running.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (Util.connectTask != null) {
                    Util.mTcpClient.sendMessage(msgArray, length);
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

I expect to implement this thread in the service (or any other option) so that on closing app sending message should not stop.